# AttributeError: 'Catalog' object has no attribute 'component'

Tags: python, sql, csv

I got this code written

But I get always error which says: AttributeError: 'Catalog' object has no attribute 'component'. the problem is that I cannot see where is the problem. Is there something wrong (maybe indentation?). Thanks

Here is snippet where it finds error

Full error code

```
 Traceback (most recent call last)
  File "C:/Users/lukasz.karasinski/Adobe CC 2020/Adobe CC 2020/Photoshop/main.py", line 186, in <module>
    catalog.export_to_sql()
  File "C:/Users/lukasz.karasinski/Adobe CC 2020/Adobe CC 2020/Photoshop/main.py", line 90, in export_to_sql
    self.export_suites_to_sql(sql_file)
  File "C:/Users/lukasz.karasinski/Adobe CC 2020/Adobe CC 2020/Photoshop/main.py", line 107, in export_suites_to_sql
    suite_guid, suite.catalog_manufacturer_guid)
  File "C:/Users/lukasz.karasinski/Adobe CC 2020/Adobe CC 2020/Photoshop/main.py", line 110, in export_components_to_sql
    for key, component in self.component.items():
AttributeError: 'Catalog' object has no attribute 'component'
```

Comment: post the traceback error and your relevant lines of code, no ones gonna read through a github repo to find your issue

Comment: Ok you are right, already updated it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trace back shows you the issue.

`for key, component in self.component.items():`

In this line self refers to `Catalog` class and as the error tells you it doesnt have any attribute called `component`. In your init method you define an attribute called `components`

```py
class Catalog:
    def __init__(self):
        self.file_signatures = {}
        self.components = {}
```

So likley you have made a typo and should change

`for key, component in self.component.items():`

to

`for key, component in self.components.items():`